# How to change the direction of values on x axis in R?

Tags: r, plot, direction

I created a plot(A, numberOfA) in `R`. On the `X axis`, I have A's parameters which the number of them are too many. By default, the `plot` show them in horizontal direction which isn't interesting when you see it due to the number of A's parameters. I was wondering if an argument exist in the `plot` function in `R` to change the direction of parameters on `X axis` to vertical. I googled, but couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `las` in `?par`:

> `las` numeric in {0,1,2,3}; the style of axis labels.
>
> 0: always parallel to the axis [default],
>
> 1: always horizontal,
>
> 2: always perpendicular to the axis,
>
> 3: always vertical.
>
> Also supported by mtext. Note that string/character rotation via
>   argument srt to par does not affect the axis labels.

So `plot(A, numberOfA, las = 3)` should get you the desired result.

---

And to quickly see it in action:

```r
plot(factor(letters), seq_along(letters))
```

[image]

```r
plot(factor(letters), seq_along(letters), las = 3)
```

[image]